# update State inside Map Function immediately React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I tried with the below code but it is executing on the second attempt, I want to execute `Alert` on the Dropdown function, I am not rendering `returnCount` just using it to display an alert,

anyone knows the answer plz answer this, don't send any link, nothing is working out instead please write the answer

```
const [arrayList, setArrayList] = useState([
        { Id: 1, Name:'A', ItemDeliveryStatus:4 },
        { Id: 2, Name:'B', ItemDeliveryStatus:4 },
        { Id: 3, Name:'C', ItemDeliveryStatus:4 },
        { Id: 4, Name:'D', ItemDeliveryStatus:4 },
      ])

const [returnCount ,setReturnCount ]=useState(0)
```

//function on the picker, want to update `returnCount` immediately so that I can use it for below alert

```
function displayalertBox(){
arrayList.map(items =>
  {
       if(items.ItemDeliveryStatus=='4')
        {
           setReturnCount(prev=> prev+1)
        }                   
  })

  if(returnCount==4)
   {
       alert('alert as returncount is equal to 4')
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use `arrayList.forEach` if you are just running a callback. Why not just just initialize a local variable to the current `returnCount` value and increment that in the loop and if the condition is met, do the alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the desired functionality inside of an `useEffect` when using react hooks.

```js
const [arrayList, setArrayList] = useState([{
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'A',
    ItemDeliveryStatus: 4
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'B',
    ItemDeliveryStatus: 4
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    Name: 'C',
    ItemDeliveryStatus: 4
  },
  {
    Id: 4,
    Name: 'D',
    ItemDeliveryStatus: 4
  },
])

const [returnCount, setReturnCount] = useState(0)


function displayalertBox() {
  arrayList.map(items => {
    if (items.ItemDeliveryStatus == '4') {
      setReturnCount(prev => prev + 1)
    }
  })


}


// You cantry this too if  needed. 
function displayalertBox1() {
  arrayList.map(items => {
    if (items.ItemDeliveryStatus == '4') {
      let count
      setReturnCount(prev => {
         count = prev + 1;
        //since state update is guaranteed, you can try this too.
        if (count === 4) {
          alert('alert as returncount is equal to 4')
        }
        return count
      })

     
    }
  })
}



useEffect(() => {

  if (returnCount == 4) {
    alert('alert as returncount is equal to 4')
  }

}, [returnCount]);
```

Comment: Please post a sample codesandbox with minimal working replication of scenario.

Comment: @asifkaif Can you please be more specific about what isn't working? This is the code I would suggest using.

Comment: i want to display alert, when displayalertBox function is called from a dropDown

Comment: displayalertBox1 please have a look if it helps

Comment: @PrakashS move the ```const count  +=  1;``` outside the function and set the state like ```setReturnCount(count)```

Comment: @Prakash alert box is display 4 times, want to display one time only

Comment: @asifkaif Either reset/change the `returnCount` state so the `returnCount === 4` condition is no longer met, or add a `showAlert` state and trigger that true when `returnCount === 4` and use a second `useEffect` to issue the alert and reset `showAlert` back to false.